# Alternate for WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a problems with new Spring Security API for my MVC and REST client

Hi, I knew that`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated and now I need use `SecurityFilterChain` and other components of Spring API.
I have Spring-Security application with REST API and MVC. Before this moment I used two instances (Component) of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` for MVC and REST. First has `HttpSecurity` for `formLogin()` authorisation (MVC). Second - for `httpBasic()` authorisation (REST). And now `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated. How I can use my mechanism with new API? Thanks!

Comment: You can find a section in the Spring Security reference documentation describing exactly this https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana ohhh, thanks so much!!! Idk why I’m not found it before :c Thanks :)